# Recursive logging crashes Interpreter in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-3.6, cpython

Following code logs an error and calls itself leading to stack overflow and eventually core dump in Python 3.6.

```
>>> import logging
>>> def rec():
...     logging.error("foo")
...     rec()
>>> rec()

[1]    101641 abort (core dumped)  python3
```

FTR, this doesn't crash Python 2.7.

Attaching the error (condensed) in Python 3.6:

```
ERROR:root:foo
...
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
...
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
...
[1]    101641 abort (core dumped)  python3
```

Python 2.7:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But no core dump in Python 2.7.

FTR, the error above with Python 3.6 will come into play if the log level is set to logging.ERROR. Similarly for other log levels.

UPDATE: I have logged [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue36272) to follow this up with the Python community.

Comment: There's no stopping condition - my test in Python 2.7 reaches maximum recursion depth. In Python 3 I guess the call stack will overflow, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle you are right of course. I'm surprised with OP's statement that it doesn't crash Python 2.7. And also with 3 upvotes...

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle Yes, there is no stopping condition and that is intentional to reproduce the error. I have also attached the errors for reference.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo The worry is that Python 3.6 aborts and dumps core thereby I loose the whole working session. It doesn't happen in Python 2.7

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo On the contrary, the difference of behavior between the 2 versions is quite significant (I guess the statement "it doesn't crash" was ambiguous though). What's mostly interesting here, by the way, is the fact that this issue is only produced when using `logging.error`, (`logging.info` produces the expected behavior of `RecursionError`). Perhaps the OP might want to add thoses precisions to his post to make it clearer

Comment: @Adonis I would say the way a program with infinite recursion crashes is insignificant as long as it dies properly and fast enough.

Comment: @SaimRaza interactive interpreter is not supposed to be used for long working sessions without keeping the relevant code elsewhere. You can do that of course but everything you type there is prone to be lost unexpectedly.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I'd agree, except that the Python interpreter allows to recover from that exception, which is not the case in this particular example. (thus imho the utility of this post)

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo ' this issue is only produced when using logging.error, (logging.info produces the expected behavior of RecursionError)' - it does crash the interpreter if log level is set to logging.INFO. I will update the answer with this observation. Thanks.

Comment: @Adonis I'm still not convinced that it's really useful. I test my code with proper tests and not with interactive interpreter. The latter is useful for quick checks which never result in loss of anything worth to worry about longer than 2 seconds.

Comment: @SaimRaza I wanted to suggest you report a bug directly to CPython developers but you already did and you seem to be successfull https://bugs.python.org/issue36272 - well done - upvoting your question now!

Answer (score 2):

Your code will eventually result in a `RuntimeError` (python 2.7) or `RecursionError` (python 3.6). This is because the recursion depth in both is limited to 1000:

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.getrecursionlimit()
1000
```

If it's actually causing a stack-overflow induced crash, one possible reason is that the recursion depth limit has been modified.

Comment: I checked the recursion limit and it is set to 1000 in both the versions.