# Django recursive logging crashes Python 3 interpreter, swallowing logs

Tags: django, python-3.x, logging

While load testing the Python 3 branch of our application, I noticed the following log entries, indicating that the maximum recursion depth had been reached, resulting in the interpreter being restarted. This leads to a massive performance hit and dropped requests.

```
WARNING [reader.views] Initializing library objects.
INFO [multiserver] Initializing ServerCoordinator with subscriptions: ['msync']
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
--- Logging error ---
Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

When looking into the issue, I noticed [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55116805/recursive-logging-crashes-interpreter-in-python-3) which I believe describes our situation (we do not have the problem with our Python 2 code), and that question led to [THIS bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue36272) and [THIS patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6a7a9f1d83cef628d2bacd71ee568b93f53fd6b4).

**My immediate goal is to make sure error and stacktrace information is properly logged, so that we can track down this issue.** According to the Python 3 source there should be a lot more information coming after `Logging Error`, but that information is totally omitted. I've traced the core Python code responsible for those logs to [this `handleError` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L931), where we can see the aforementioned patch. My sense is that the outer try-block emits an exception that is subsequently swallowed.

---

**What have I tried so far:**

- Confirm that `raiseExceptions` is set to `True`. No change.
- I used the `find_recursionlimit.py` [script](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Tools/scripts/find_recursionlimit.py) in the Python 3 repo to find our system's real recursion depth limit, and modified it from the default of `1000` to `11800`. No change.
- Limited the complexity of LOGGING settings, removing custom handlers and filters. No change.

---

**What I'm considering or actively working on:**

- Patching the `handleError` function to raise exceptions in the outer try-block
- Wrapping the `logging` package to try to effect the same change

---

**More information**

- Django 1.11
- Python 3.7
- Logging configuration [LINK](https://gist.github.com/LorenzoFernando/01e9a291212455c3f038e7e79c9403e4)